# Highlight certain days in react-dates

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I have a `DayPickerRangeController` from [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates), defined like this:

```js
<DayPickerRangeController
    startDate={start}
    endDate={end}
    onDatesChange={onDatesChange}
    firstDayOfWeek={1}
    numberOfMonths={3}
    focusedInput={focusedDateInput}
    onFocusChange={e => setFocussedDateInput(e as FocusedInputShape)}
/>
```

I also have some API that returns a value for a set of dates. I'm trying to find a way to change the color of certain days, based on whatever the API returns.

Looking at the [implementation of their themes](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/src/theme/DefaultTheme.js), there doesn't seem to be a way, to change the style of certain days.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to style individual days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `isDayHighlighted` prop.

You can find out an example on how to use it [there](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-day-props--with-some-highlighted-dates.)

If you really want to implement your own style to certain days, you can use the `renderDayContents` prop.

An example is available on a github issue [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/374#issuecomment-288380583)

```
<DayPicker
    renderDayContents={(day) => (day.day() % 6 === 5 ? ":)" : day.format('D'))}
/>
```